# Are dirs in C:\Users\Public\Documents writable to everyone by default?

Tags: windows, permissions, path

I want my installer to create a folder in `C:\Users\Public\Documents` that will be readable and writable to all local users. This includes the right to create files/dirs there, and to modify and delete all existing ones. The installer is being ran as Administrator.

I don't have to programatically set the permissions for my dir, right? Just by creating the dir, it will have the correct permissions I think.

I'm interested in the behavior under XP, Vista and 7.

Note: I'm not hardcoding the path `C:\Users\Public\Documents`, I'm querying `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` from the Win API, which can return different values depending on machine and OS. For example on XP it returns a different path.

**Edit:** [here's](http://www.vbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vb/35159/Folder-Permissions) a relevant discussion. It points to MS docs about the question, but it also looks like those docs may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it inherits rights from the parent folder.  Which has write permission for anybody in the INTERACTIVE group.  Which includes any logged-in user account.

Use the Security tab in the shell's Properties dialog to review these settings.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to a reference? The [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx) say: *By default, only 
the creator of the document (and administrators) will be able to 
subsequently modify the document.*

Comment: @Stefan, that documentation is for Windows 2000!